# Change extjs store page param to zero-base

Tags: extjs

I have server backend, which accepts zero-based page parameter for chunk data loading.

But Extjs, by default, operates 1-based page index.

Is there any way I can change `Ext.data.Store` page parameter to zero-based?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use just out-of-the-box store paging methods I believe you can just overrite [`loadPage`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-loadPage) method, like this:

```
loadPage: function(page, options) {
    ...

    options = Ext.apply({
        // Overrite this row
        page: page - 1,
        start: (page - 1) * me.pageSize,
        limit: me.pageSize,
        addRecords: !me.clearOnPageLoad
    }, options);

    ...
},
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I hoped that there should be just a config option to do the job, but eventually I ended up with alike solution.